# Chart js showing squares

Tags: node.js, docker, charts, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I am using the npm module [chartjs-node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node-canvas) to create the chart and add it to my xlsx file .
I am getting the wanted result without running my app as a dokcer container .
Here the result got after running my app with docker :
[image]

And here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:16.13.1-alpine3.13
RUN apk add dumb-init
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache  pixman
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat && ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
RUN apk add --no-cache  libuuid
RUN apk add --no-cache  glib
RUN apk add --update  autoconf gcc g++ make libaio-dev libnsl gettext-dev automake libtool libc6-compat
RUN apk add --update libaio libnsl &&  ln -s /usr/lib/libnsl.so.2 /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1
RUN apk add musl-dev libaio autoconf && apk add --update make
RUN apk add --update && apk add --no-cache ffmpeg opus pixman cairo pango giflib ca-certificates  && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps git curl build-base jpeg-dev pixman-dev
RUN apk --no-cache --virtual .canvas-build-deps add  build-base  cairo-dev  jpeg-dev  pango-dev  giflib-dev  pixman-dev pangomm-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype-dev  && apk --no-cache add  pixman  cairo  pango  giflib
RUN apk --no-cache --virtual .canvas-build-deps add build-base  cairo-dev jpeg-dev pango-dev  giflib-dev pixman-dev  pangomm-dev  libjpeg-turbo-dev  freetype-dev 
RUN apk --no-cache add pixman  cairo  pango  giflib
```

Comment: That Dockerfile doesn't seem to include any Javascript code, just a large number of host OS dependencies (largely oriented around a C toolchain).  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem is not about the javascript code of charjs , because it works fine when i run the project with pm2 or with node command directly on my ubuntu 20 system .
It is about this docker image 'node:16.13.1-alpine3.13'

Comment: @chihebbelhajali I'm having exactly same issue. Could you please tell what was problem with that docker image and how did you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly why but I was experiencing the same issue with `node:16-alpine` and it was fixed by using `node:16`.

Comment: because the canvas dependency of the system cannot be installet on an alpine image

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I installed `fontconfig`:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    fontconfig
```

Now it works

AWS lambda returned this error:

```
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case, the problem was there wasn't any font installed in docker.
I solve it by installing fonts in host machine: `apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` then copy fonts to docker: `docker cp /usr/share/fonts DOCKER_CONTAINER:/usr/share/`
After restart the container, everything works as expected.